# 28" TFT for under $350

Tags: monitors

I'm looking for an alternative 28" TFT to the Dell P2815Q due to the rise of its price:
[image: Dell P2815Q price trend]

It should be a TFT around 28" with a resolution of 3840 x 2160 (Ultra HD).
I don't see any other requierements except a price below $350, I'm currently using a iiyama and the quality should be equal. If anybody knows the reason for the price fluctuation, I would be interested (OT).

Comment: Hi de-facto, your question doesn't appear to meet the current [quality guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/206/155). Could you provide us with a list of specific requirements for a potential monitor?

Comment: "28-inch monitor, 3840x2160" doesn't narrow things down very much.  Are there specific features of the Dell (eg. panel technology) that you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually not. The only criterias are the resolution and the size. Price should be below € 350. A higher refrash rate would be great, as it is only 30 Hz for the Dell. It sould be the same quality respectively the cost-benefits should be similar. I would also invest in a monitor from a different company for the same price, if recommended.

Comment: That's an older dell model, and its wierd the price rose. The newer ones are awesome tho. SST, colour caliberation, and so on. Not quite in your price range tho

Comment: Does no one use newegg.com or amazon.com on their own before coming here anymore?

Comment: Still looking? If so, would 27" be fine?

Answer (score 8):

I was assuming you're pretty much going to have to get a TV at that price, and you might be running at a lower refresh rate.

I instead picked up a [Crossover 289K](http://www.crosslcd.co.kr/main.html?tmp=product&pg=289k), sight unseen. Its an interesting series of compromises that seem to add up to something I'd recommend). I've been running it for over a year now, and its been fine so far.

I paid ~ USD 350 with shipping and prices from ebay and prices seem to vary a few dollars from week to week

[image]

(To the left, the crossover, to the right, my dell. Sorry for the potato quality photos)

Its a bit short, so its on a crate. If it worked for kylie...

While you can never trust the pictures sellers use, the 'official' beauty shot shows off the industrial design pretty well

[image]

Has Displayport, most modern conveniences including an OSD (which many of these don't have) and a adjustable stand. This particular model doesn't seem to have a perfect pixel guarantee which may or may not be an issue for you.  Mine was *perfect*.

Looks like all the HDMI ports do 4k60, which wasn't documented anywehre.

Box contents for me were a manual, a french style power connector, an *entirely standard* 12V PSU (so, if yours dies, you can replace it with a suitable *standard* unit). The PSU was nestled into the packaging so some digging was needed. You also get a fairly solid DP cable (which despite some reports about such monitors does 2160p60 quite happily). That strange triangle is a screwdriver used to screw the base in.

The base itself is a slab of what feels like tempered glass with 3 holes in it, which screw into a bit of extruded aluminium screwed into the back of the monitor. I found it easier to unscrew the 4 screws connecting the monitor to the aluminium, screwing in the base and screwing it on. You might also choose to ditch that for the entirely standard VESA mount.

The monitor has a pretty impressive set of inputs/outputs. One DP, 3 x HDMI 2.0 (one of which does MHL) , one VGA (1080p only) and a USB port for use with a basic onboard media player. It also supports HCDP 2.0 though there's no way for me to check.

[image]

This model has a *remote control* as an option. Get it.

Considering the lovely, large, very well labelled buttons are *behind* the screen, it is probably handy.

[image]

They are lovely, large buttons and labelled through the front.

Its beautifully sharp, though its TN and not as good, colourwise as my IPS. Still, its a great, sharp monitor for not much money. Colour caliberation went a long way.

Like many of these cheap screens, it seems to have some degree of backlight bleed, but this is primarily obvious in perfect darkness and I'm planning on experimenting with bias lighting to see if it helps. Would still totally recommend this as a second monitor.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations! 35" is too big for me, as I want to use the screen on a not so big table. But the price is awesome! I'm not sure if I could trust the Crossover regarding quality requirements. Where do you know Crossover from? I'm not sure if there is any European reseller.

Comment: Quite a few people used to buy quad HD IPS monitors from these korean vendors. They tend to be cheap and stripped down, but people typically seem to like them for what they are. They also ship to europe. Its a bit of a risk, but at your specifications/price range its still tricky to get a big manufacturer with a Grade A panel and warranty. That said, I'd seriously consider this for a second monitor when the time comes, simply cause its pretty hard to go 4K at that price point! While its for QHD http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/449537-korean-monitor-guide/ talks about various brands of monitors.

Comment: I've ordered a 289K, its a newer version, TN, and once I've gotten it, I'll update this post.

Comment: Ok. I resolved my problem by buying a used one (for quite a few bucks) with 2.5 years warranty left, in the condition of a new one.

Comment: Ahh, I'd suggest posting what you did as an answer, explaining your reasoning, and picking it as the correct answer.