# FullHD+ monitor with 4 HDMI inputs

Tags: monitors, hdmi

I have 2 PCs (1 personal, 1 company), an Amazon FireTV and a Raspberry Pi 2. All those devices have HDMI output. My company laptop has Display Port as well.

Being a software developer, I need high resolution for the PCs. At the moment I use 2 monitors with 1280x1024, but IMHO FullHD would be sufficient as a minimum resolution. Higher resolution probably preferred.

The FireTV supports 4k, but I can't see the advantage of 4k yet. FullHD is nice enough. From the description, it seems I need HDCP 2.2 support.

I am sitting in front of the monitor at a distance of .8 to 1 meter, so the size in inches should probably not be too large. Right now I have 2 monitors with 17", which is ok.

Requirements list:

- FullHD or higher resolution
- 4 inputs in total (4 HDMI or 3 HDMI + 1 DP)
- 1 HDMI input must support HDCP 2.2
- switching between inputs should be "easy"
- operation without remote control

I don't necessarily need:

- short reaction times, since I'll not do game play with it
- 3D support
- other inputs (although a standard D-Sub VGA input would be nice - who knows what it'll be good for)

At the moment I don't care about the price yet. I just want to find a monitor that has 4 HDMI inputs.

I have tried: finding a monitor on Amazon. From my filter there are 174 monitors to review and while I can specify HDMI, I can't specify the amount of inputs.

Comment: So are you looking for one large, wide monitor, or 2 ~17" monitors?

Comment: @Downgoat: One large monitor

Comment: Hm, I doubt there's a monitor with 4 HDMI ports but your best bet would probably be to get a [switcher](http://amzn.com/B00RQU9HWY).

Comment: Would 3 and a dp input work for you? Any preferred *size*?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Yes, 3 HDMI + 1 DP is an option. I am thinking of 24".

Comment: @Downgoat: If there are no monitors with multiple inputs, I'll try a HMDI switcher. I dislike that it is another device which needs another HDMI cable and another power supply. My desk is already messy with all the cables from printer, scanner etc.

Comment: I've got something that meets most of those specifications, if I can check for HDCP2.2 support I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2):

I've posted another [answer and pictures here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/682/28-tft-for-under-350/709#709) but I'd recommend the [crossover 289K](http://www.crosslcd.co.kr/main.html?tmp=product&pg=289k). I got mine for ~350usd from an ebay
seller called dream-seller though if you're us based there might be cheaper options to buy it from

Its 28" but meets *most* of the specifications. I've got no way to check for HDCP 2.2 support and I cannot confirm that it supports it. Information on support is, to put it mildly, as clear as mud.

Otherwise

FullHD or higher resolution: 4K60hz Above spec but its not a terribly pricy monitor

4 inputs in total: (4 HDMI or 3 HDMI + 1 DP) 3HDMI 2.0 and 1 DP port, all supporting 4K60. One 1080p VGA input for legacy gear

1 HDMI input must support HDCP 2.2: <strike>Unsure - there's no way to check. Nvidia reports it suggests HDCP but not what version. I'll be glad to run any reasonable check that can be run on a windows box.</strike> Their horribly designed website suggests it does support it.

switching between inputs should be "easy": Hit select, pick an input with the arrow buttons, hit select again. Really nice OSD, though button placement is *behind* the screen to save on bezel space. Nice large buttons  and I didn't have too many issues hitting the correct one. Heck it was easier than the side buttons on my old dell.

operation without remote control:  Optional remote - which I love to bits. I just hit source to switch sources. Very handy when caliberating the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The [Fujitsu P Line P27T-7 UHD](http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/ds-display-p27t-7-uhd.pdf)

- Resolution: 3840x2160 (27")
- Inputs: 1x HDMI 2.0, 2x HDMI 1.4 (MHL), 1x DisplayPort 1.2
- Input selection: input button at the front
- HDCP support according to a [idealo.de review](http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/3785017_-p27t-7-fujitsu.html) (version not known)

[image: Input selection]

Warning: Some older versions with the same number seem to have different inputs.

Comment: The idealo.de link you provide correspond to the _Fujitsu P27T-7 LED_ with only 2560 x 1440 resolution; not to the _Fujitsu P27T-7 UHD_ with 4K native (3840x2160) resolution. Good church but wrong pew.